# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\php\conexion.php on line 3

Tags: php

lo que sucede es que cuando trato de ingresar o registrarme me aparece esto:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting
>   end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\php\conexion.php on line 3

este es mi código:

```
      <?php

private $servidor="localhost";
private $usuario="root";
private $password="";
private $bd_usu="limpieza_es";

?>


        <div class="contenido">
        <h3>FORMULARIO DE  REGISTRO</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text"  name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" required autofocus/>
            <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" class="form-control" id="apellido" require/>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email"  class="form-control" id="email" require/>
            <label for="tel">Telefono:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" require/>
            <label for="con">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" name="con" class="form-control" id="con" require/>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Registrar</button>

        </div>


        </form>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Agradezco su colaboración...

Comment: Elimina el private, no es necesario puesto que no estas trabajando con encapsulamiento.

Answer (score 4):

Los modificadores de acceso tales como:

- `public`
- `private`
- `protected`

Indican el alcance que tendrás de estos mismos *(métodos y propiedades)* por fuera de la clase que los contiene.

Lo anterior entonces indica que si no estas programando bajo un paradigma de *POO*, entonces dichos modificadores no tienen sentido y además como puedes notar generarán un error de sintaxis, ya que dicha *keyword* solo es válida si existe dentro del contexto de una clase.

**Esto sería válido**

```
class Ejemplo
{
    private $servidor="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $password="";
    private $bd_usu="limpieza_es";
}
```

- Entonces alcanza con eliminar dicha *keyword* y todo debería funcionar.

**Referencia**

- [Modificadores de acceso](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)